# How do we ensure scale in protection for kubernetes pods?

Tags: kubernetes, hpa

While scaling-in, HPA shouldn't terminate a pod that has a job running on it.
This is taken care of by AWS autoscaling groups in the form of scale-in protection for instances. Is there something similar in kubernetes?

Answer (score 1):

You use terminationGracePeriodSeconds to make your worker process wait until it is done. It will get a SIGTERM, then has that many seconds to finish (default 9 but you can make it anything, some of my workers have it set to 12 hours), then SIGKILL if it hasn't exited. So stop accepting new work units on SIGTERM, set the threshold to be the length of your longest work unit, and no worries :)